# Python: string counts in a nested loop to 2d matrix and returning "context" string

Tags: python

I've written a small program that runs through a text looking for character combinations.

```
text=('file.txt')
unique = ('p','b','t','d','k','g','r','l')
for x in unique:
    for y in unique:
        twoC = (x+y)        
        twoC_find=text.count(twoC)
        txt_file = open('twoC.txt', 'a')
        txt_file.write(twoC+' '+str(twoC_find)+'\n')
txt_file.close()
```

It lists all character combinations and their number of occurrences in the txt file, and prints them to another txt file. There are two further things I would like to accomplish here, but I'm not sure where to look next.

1. instead of (or in addition to) a list of x+y and their number of occurrences, I would like to create a 2d list of x and y with values as number of occurrences:

   ```
        p    b    t    etc        
   p    5    10   2 
   b    0    0    7 
   t    0    13   11
   etc
   ```
2. I would like to return a list of words (defined by white space) in which the string is found, so if:

   ```
   twoC = br
   ```

the script would return 'brzeszcze', 'zabronić', 'żubr', etc. Ideally, I would like to store them in a list of variables (eg br_twoC, containing all words, then another list like twoC_combinations=(br_twoC, bl_twoC, gd_twoC, etc..), so I could further manipulate and print them as examples at the end of the text_file.

I have experimented with the .find() function, but this returns a single index and I don't really know (a) how to return an index for more than one instance and (b) how to return everything around that index in both directions until white space. Maybe there's a better option than find.

If someone could offer tips on where to look for example of these kinds of things, I would be grateful!

Comment: Do not open your file in a for loop, just open it once outside the loop.

Comment: Thanks! Not a programmer (obv.!), so all tips welcome.

Comment: For the occurrence overview you can use a dict with a tuple as key. If you want to keep a list per combination, a dict with a list value would do.

Comment: Thanks. I'll get googling...

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve my issue number 1. Thanks @Johan van Breda; probably it's not what you had in mind, but here's what I came up with after searching the keywords you sent and thinking it over some more:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

text=('file.txt')
unique = ('p','b','t','d','k','g','r','l')
twoC_list=['C']
twoC_list=twoC_list+unique
twoC_list=[twoC_list]

for x in unique:
    C1=x
    C1_list=[C1]
    for y in unique:
        twoC = (x+y)
        twoC_count=text.count(twoC)
        C1_list.append(twoC_count)
    twoC_list.append(C1_list)

twoC_array=np.array(twoC_list, dtype=object)
df = pd.DataFrame(twoC_array)
df.to_csv("twoC_array.csv")
```

I would be shocked if there *wasn't* a more elegant solution (comments welcome), but hey, it works.

I'm still stuck on the number 2 question – how to isolate and list the words (defined by white space) in which my twoC is found? Any ideas? keywords?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

for number two, I would use regular expression

```
import re
re.findall("\w*" + twoC + "\w*", s, re.UNICODE)
```

where s is the string you are searching. In the above expression, \w* matches 0 or more occurrences of Unicode word characters letters, followed by your twoC, followed again by /w*

It returns a list containing all matching words.

```
s = 'brzeszcze zabronić żubr WhoWhatWhenWhy hello blah' 
re.findall("\w*" + twoC + "\w*", s, re.UNICODE)
```

returns  `['brzeszcze', 'zabronić', 'żubr']`

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a go.

Comment: Thanks @ VanTan. It works like this for the words. Can I modify the re.findall line to only return twoC at the beginning, middle, or end of the word? I've been looking at the re documentation since your comment, but I don't see it immediately.

Comment: That is fairly easy to do. Read up here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html. To match only at at the beginning, you would do "^" + twoC + "\w+". in the Middle: "\w+" + twoC + "\w+". At the end:"\w*" + twoC + "$"

Comment: Thanks. First and last didn't work like this, but I used r"\b"+twoC+"\w*|" and "\w*"+twoC+r"\b". It seems to be working now.

Comment: Sorry, "^" and "$" are for beginning and end of string. You had asked for word!